# HttpServlet - How to know if SSL Client Authentication is used

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, ssl, jax-ws

I have a `Servlet` container (Glassfish/OC4J) which service some JAX-WS web service endpoints which can be reach using HTTPS. The SSL is configured to support both Client Authentication and Server only authentication (like client-auth="want" on Glassfish).

In my endpoint implementation I want to know if the connection was done with or without Client authentication. I already have access to the `HttpServletRequest` object, but the `getAuthType()` method is always returning null, no mater if Client auth is done or not (checked using wireshark to be sure it does what I want).

Does anybody knows how to have access to such info ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: yes Glassfish is used in this case, but I'm using other containers like OC4J also, and I would be nice to have a solution that work for both.

Comment: update the question to add Glassfish and oc4j

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` request attribute should return an array of [java.security.cert.X509Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html).

You can get it from your request using:

```
X509Certificate[] certs = req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

If non-null, and if it contains something, the first element (`certs[0]`) will be the client certificate itself. There may be other elements in this array, which will contain intermediate CA certificates (what's presented by the client can be a certificate chain), where `cert[i]` is issued by `cert[i+1]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exaclty what I needed. I just tested it on Glassfish, let's just hope it works fine on OC4J

Comment: It's part of the Servlet specification, so it should work across containers.